# How to export and import `alias` from previous version of EasyPHP?

Tags: php, import, export, alias, easyphp

At the moment when installing new version of EasyPHP on my Windows 7 OS, I've got to re-add the alias on my machine which is a boring process since I have teens of projects running on my machine.

I'm looking for way to export alias(es) in old version and use them to import into new version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your old `conf_files/httpd.conf`, copy **the end of the file** (between `#alias` and starts with `### Alias EasyPHP`) and paste it in the new one.

Then restart the servers. That's it!

Regards